# Inserting spaces " " into a table file using Python to separate columns

Tags: python, file, vim, format, fwrite

I have a table file that looks like this:

```
3 5415.00    6.00 -1998.3 -781.28 21.98 9.99 3.41  21.63 0.94 1.29 0 -98.04  98.04
4 6443.00    6.00 -1998.3-1216.10 21.71 0.35 0.38  22.78 8.00 3.00 2 -98.04  98.04
5 5806.00    7.00 -1997.8 -946.67 21.04 0.19 0.19  23.26 6.27 0.97 0   2.23  -2.23
6 7882.00    8.00 -1997.4-1824.80 22.18 0.58 0.49  22.62 0.85 0.85 0   0.44  -0.44
7 3278.00    9.00 -1997.0  122.67 20.94 0.24 0.20  23.53 8.00 0.24 2 -98.04  98.04
```

As you can see there are certain values that exceed the expected space it should take and get rid of the space between the columns, causing my code unable to read the file, stating there are less columns than the rest.

An advantage is that I can know in which exact columns (may happen in several) of the file this happens, so I can implement a code or function that inserts a space into these columns to every line of the file.

I'm not very familiar with writing/reading files, so I'm guessing the thought above is the simplest way to solve this. Cheers.

Comment: Would it be possible to sort this problem during creation of the file? Also do you care about file readability? Do particular columns have specific number of digits?

Comment: The files are already created and were handed to me. I will need to return these files with this problem fixed, so they will need to have the same order. The two conflicting columns in the example may have one less digit each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, if you don't know exactly where all the "mistakes" are, you're going to have to read the entire file anyway.

Insofar as that's true, I'd say that your approach (to go and add a space in every line at column n) is actually pretty efficient.

I'd also suggest looking into Vim's blockwise visual mode.
For example (modified from [jubi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5095753/jubi)):

1. Go to the column you need to
2. Ctrl + v (to enter in visual mode)
3. Use the arrow keys to select the lines
4. Shift + i (takes you to insert mode)
5. Hit space keys or whatever you want to type in front of the selected lines.
6. Save the changes (Use :w) and now you will see the changes in all the selected lines.

Here's another source: [How to insert a block of white spaces starting at the cursor position in vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592314/how-to-insert-a-block-of-white-spaces-starting-at-the-cursor-position-in-vi)

Hope it works!

Comment: I used Vim and followed your steps and worked exactly how I wanted. Although scrolling through the ~30k lines takes a little bit (there's probably a faster way to get to the bottom line), it solves the problem just fine. Thanks! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

First things first. It's not possible to solve this problem after the file is generated. Imagine that you have merged columns into: `6 7882.00 8.00 -1997.41824.80 22.18 0.58 0.49 22.62 0.85 0.85 0 0.44 -0.44`. Notice the `-1997.41824.80`. **There is no way to split that into two columns.**

Best approach here would to be use different columns seperator in the original file (during creation of the file) - for example `;` since it's not used as decimal seperator and is commonly used in csv files.

Second way to solve this works only if you know how many digits there is in the columns (which is not a case here, since there is diffent number of digits in your provided example).

After you receive your file with different separator your data should look like:

```
3;5415.00;6.00;-1998.3;-781.28;21.98;9.99;3.41;21.63;0.94;1.29;0;-98.04;98.04
```

Then you can use `csv` library, `pandas.read_csv()`, or write custom code which would looked like this:

```
file_with_data = open("filename.txt", "r")
raw_data = file_with_data.read()
file_with_data.close()
rows = raw_data.split("\n")  #splitting whole file to list containing rows
for row in rows:
    print(row.split(";"))  # splitting row data into values based on the ; seperator
```