# vi mark the first character after inserting spaces in visual block

Tags: vi

I am new to vi, and tried to insert some spaces in the beginning of several lines. I followed [How to insert a block of white spaces starting at the cursor position in vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592314/how-to-insert-a-block-of-white-spaces-starting-at-the-cursor-position-in-vi)
 solution and it succeeded however after it, vi marked the first character of all the line in the file with blue/purpule marking, that I couldn't get rid of. it doesn't affect the file, but just annoyance in my eyes... Anybody knows what it is ? what is the purpose of it ? and how you remove this marking ?

Comment: which answer in the the question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592314/how-to-insert-a-block-of-white-spaces-starting-at-the-cursor-position-in-vi

did you use?
Can you provide a screen shot or something?

Comment: did it go when you typed "v" again?